# XSLT 2.0 stransfer data between template

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I want know it is possible to transfer a variable in template  and get value. For example set variable in template A  and get value in template B ?
I try to use call-template but i don't get value.

```
<xsl:template name="Transf">
  <xsl:param name="T1"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$T1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='director/filmDirectors'>
   <xsl:if test="filmDirector='Allen Woody'">
      <xsl:call-template name="Transf">
       <xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:with-param name="T1" select="@id"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='movie/titles'>
 <xsl:call-template name="Transf">
  <xsl:with-param name="T1"><xsl:value-of select="tile[@id=$T1]"/></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

XML file

```
<list>
 <director>
   <filmDirectors>
    <filmDirector id="steve-s">
     <lname>Spielberg</lname>
     <lfirstname>Steven</lfirstname>
    </filmDirector>

   <filmDirector id="woody-a">
    <lname>Allen<lname>
    <lfirstname>Woody</lfirstname>
   </filmDirector>
 <filmDirectors>
</director>

<movie>
 <titles>
   <title id="steve-s">Jurassic Park</title>
 </titles>
 <titles>
   <title id="woody-a">Small Time Crooks</title>
 </titles>
</movie>
```

Can you give me advice ?

Thank you in advance your reply.

Comment: The given templates don't compile. You can't use if statements in a call-template...

Comment: The provided "xml" is severely malformed. Please, edit the question and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to give a solution without knowing the structure of your XML, but the general idea is to use apply-templates instead of call-templates. A solution might appear as follows.

```
<xsl:template match='director/filmDirectors'>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="filmDirectors" select="." tunnel="yes" />
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='movie/titles'>
  <xsl:param name="filmDirectors" tunnel="yes" />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('title: ',.,' director: ',$filmDirectors)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: tunnelling variables can only be used in xslt 2.0, and isn't necessary for the given solution

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But can you explain why we use concat ? There is no way possible ?

Comment: I just used the concat function as a way of formatting results for the output that includes the value of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**I think your problem is here**:

```
<xsl:template match='movie/titles'>
 <xsl:call-template name="Transf">
  <xsl:with-param name="T1"><xsl:value-of select="tile[@id=$T1]"/></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

You are referencing a variable/parameter named `$T1`, but there is no such-named variable/parameter defined in the template.

**Unless there is a *global* variable/parameter named `$T1`, the above code will cause a compile-time error**.

**There is another, severe error in:**

```
<xsl:template match='director/filmDirectors'>
   <xsl:call-template name="Transf">
     <xsl:if test="filmDirector='Allen Woody'">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:with-param name="T1" select="@id"/>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

**`xsl:if` cannot be a child of `xsl:call-template"**

**My recommendation for you is to read an introductory book on XSLT, before asking questions full of errors**.